# MSScriptControl 'Specified cast is not valid' when exposing an object to VBScript

Tags: c#, api, vbscript, scripting

I'm trying to implement scripting capability to my application. I'm using the code below. Whenever I instantiate a new `Api` object, the application is supposed to quit (a little testing thing :p)

However, the application crashes at `script.AddObject(...)` with the error `Specified cast is not valid.` Is there a step I'm missing here?

```
public class ApiExposed
{
    public string ModuleName;

    public void Exit()
    {
        System.Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
public class Api
{
    ScriptControlClass script;
    ApiExposed ApiObj;

    public Api()
    {
        ApiObj = new ApiExposed();

        script = new ScriptControlClass();
        script.Language = "VBScript";
        script.AddObject("tbapi", (object)ApiObj, true);

        script.Eval("tbapi.Exit()");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, the ApiExposed class is not COM visible - it will need to be in order for VBScript to interact with it.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems to this.

Make sure you use `[ComVisible(true)]` on the class and methods.
Also, make your class PUBLIC!